# Skype web-SDK dependencies unclear

Tags: ucma, skype-for-business, ucwa, skypedeveloper

I am planning to make a soft phone JQuery plug-in with the new Skype web-SDK.
It is still unclear to me if the web-sdk depends on UCWA or that it can be used with the classic UCMA as well, and does it require Office365 for on-premise UCMA / UCWA machines like a cloud hosted instance.

Also what is the current availability of UCWA?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been recently announced, during Build 2016 conference, that UCWA as well as Skype Web SDK is now available also for Office 365 customers.

UCMA is still only available to customers with on-premises Lync 2013 / SfB installation

Refer to this documentation: [Skype Developer Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt650889.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the answer here [skype document](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/03/introducing-skype-for-business-web-sdk/).

> What’s worth mentioning here is that UCMA is still not supported in Skype for Business Online, and at launch the Skype Web SDK will not be supported Online. Also, only Basic support for the Web SDK will be available in Lync 2013. I don’t know what that means exactly, but when I find out I’ll let you know!

Still a bit vague for my taste

Answer (score 0):

Enzo - Your reference is more than a year old. We have launched Skype Web SDK for online. It depends on UCWA, which is also now available for online.